# Как отследить и обработать что файл был открыт моей программой на базе SwiftUI

Tags: файлы, swift, swiftui

У меня есть программа которая должна уметь открывать изображения

Программа уже ассоциирована с неким набором расширений использая `plist` file:

[image]

Так что я уже имею возможность открывать при помощи меню "Open with":

[image]

---

Итак мой вопрос:

Как мне достать URL открытого файла через мою SwiftUI-based программу?

что бы дальше работать с этим файлом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WindowGroup {
    SampleView()
        .onOpenURL { url in
            //это и есть этот url который был открыт программой
        }
    }
}
```